# Sqlite database insert data from other table is inserting one row only

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have the issue while inserting data from product table which contains 3 rows with quote_id =1 I am only able to get first one from product to price table.

Code to insert in price

```
db.execsql("insert into price (name, quantity ) values ((select from product title, quantity where quote_id =1 )  )   " )
```

Updated :

i want to insert a static id of one in same statment;
value = 1;

```
insert into price (price_id,name, quantity,row_total) 
"+value+",select title, quantity,SUM(price*quantity) 
from product where quote_id = 1
```

Something this i want to acheive this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the correct syntax. Try this:

```
insert into price (price_id, name, quantity) 
select 1, title, quantity 
from product 
where quote_id = 1
```

You must **not** use the keyword `values` in this case.
This will return all rows `where quote_id = 1` from `product` table and insert them into `price` table.
If there is only 1 row returned then this 1 row will be inserted.
Are there any other constraints in `price` table that do not allow the insertion of more rows, like unique indexes?
**Edit**:

```
db.execsql(
    "insert into price (price_id, name, quantity) select " + 
     value + 
    ", title, quantity from product where quote_id = 1");
```

Comment: Did you remove `values`?

Comment: Yes i did and its working .Can you help in one more thing i want to insert a static value as price id in same insert statment.

Comment: What is the name of the column where it will be inserted? And what is the static value?

Comment: This will work only if `price_id` is **not unique** if you want to insert multiple items with price_id = 1.

Comment: Can you review edited question again. your answer is giving error for no coloumn value exists

Comment: There is no column value in my code. Did you copy and paste it as it is?

Comment: yes its working. One last thing if you can help i want to insert row_total in price which is product table quantity*price. how can i do it as i am using sum(price*quantity) and its again resulting in one row

Comment: Where does `price` come from?

Comment: I got it thank you vaery much for helping me. Well price was in product table

Comment: Then remove `SUM()`, use only `price*quantity` in your code. `SUM()` sums over all the rows of the table.

Answer (score 0):

If 'quote_id' is the primary key of the price table, and the 'quote_id's from the product table are the same, then you are just overwriting the same record.

If that is not the case, then I recommend querying product to make sure there are multiple records with quote_id = 1.

Comment: quote_id is not primary key. In products i have multiple coloumns with quote_id 1 which i want to insert in price. Can you explain query method

Answer (score 0):

db.execsql("insert into price (name, quantity) select title, quantity from product where quote_id = 1")